# Memory leak in loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im using `AsyncTask`. There are 2  methods: `doInBackground` and `onProgressUpdate`. `doInBackground` has loop in which downloading `JsonObj` and then `onProgressUpdate` create a new UI. Code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount() ; i++) {
 URL url = new URL(adress);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();
 InputStream inputStream;
inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    resultJson = buffer.toString();
}
dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);
                    if(dataJsonObj.has("obj") && !dataJsonObj.isNull("obj")) {
                        JSONObject obj= dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("obj");
                        String some= obj.getString("some");
                         publishProgress(some);                    }
}catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
```

When I start it, in LogCat writing next(**not for each loop, after 2-3 runs of loop**):

> GC_CONCURRENT freed 350K, 11% free 4033K/4500K, paused 4ms+0ms, total
>   8ms

In this loop `publishProgress` doesn`t work, but next loop it works well again. I guess its memory leak(too much "new objects in loop"), but Im not sure.
How to fix it? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Run `LeakCanary` and identify which objects are causing memory leaks, then wrap then in `WeakReference` to make sure they can be GC'd. And hope that little trivial change fixes it :)

Comment: What are you doin on progressUpdate? You should not be creating new UI there, just update old views. also publishProgress, should take int

Comment: @X3Btel If run `doInBackground` only(without `onProgressUpdate`) GC_CONCURRENT calling does not matter. So i think that problem somewhere in `doInBackground` ..

Comment: are you disconnecting the url connections? It seems you are only opening them. Also do you really need to use loop to make requests?

Comment: @X3Btel Im try `urlConnection.disconnect()` in the end of loop/add in `catch` but it not works..